# How to display Popup of ComboBox above?

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

My custom ComboBox works is correctly, but I do not understand how to up popup with list of element above of combobox.

```
ComboBox {
    id: pointsPositionComboBox
    anchors.fill: parent
    displayText: qsTr("Position point")
    model: map.pointPositionModel
    textRole: "name"
    delegate: Row {
        Rectangle {
            id: delegateRect
            width: pointsPositionRect.width - removePointRect.width
            height: pointsPositionRect.height
            color: {
                if (!delegateRectMouseArea.containsMouse)
                    return "#25263C"
                else if (delegateRectMouseArea.containsMouse
                         && !delegateRectMouseArea.pressed) {
                    return "#5F8C6D"
                } else if (delegateRectMouseArea.containsMouse
                           && delegateRectMouseArea.pressed) {
                    return "#73AB84"
                }
            }

            Text {
                text: model.name
                color: "white"
                width: parent.width - removePointItem.width
                font.pixelSize: pointsPositionComboBox.font.pixelSize
                anchors.topMargin: pointsPositionRect.height / 3
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 5
            }
            MouseArea {
                id: delegateRectMouseArea
                anchors.fill: delegateRect
                hoverEnabled: true
                acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
                onClicked: {
                    if (hasUserMenuProperty.hasUserMenu()
                            && !globalUserManager.hasAccessToPrivilege("controlMap"))
                        return

                    const latitude = model.position.latitude
                    const longitude = model.position.longitude

                    map.center.latitude = latitude
                    map.center.longitude = longitude
                    map.zoomLevel = model.zoomLevel
                    globalMapProperty.bearing = model.bearing

                    pointsPositionComboBox.popup.close()
                }
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: removePointRect
            width: 30
            height: 30
            z: pointsPositionComboBox.z + 1
            color: {
                if (!removePointItemMouseArea.containsMouse)
                    return "#25263C"
                else if (removePointItemMouseArea.containsMouse
                         && !removePointItemMouseArea.pressed) {
                    return "#73A081"
                } else if (removePointItemMouseArea.containsMouse
                           && removePointItemMouseArea.pressed) {
                    return "#52785E"
                }
            }
            Image {
                id: removePointItem
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                source: removePointItemMouseArea.containsMouse ? "qrc:/icons/compass/remove_point_en.svg"
                                                               : "qrc:/icons/compass/remove_point_dis.svg"
            }
            MouseArea {
                id: removePointItemMouseArea
                anchors.fill: removePointRect
                hoverEnabled: true
                acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
                onClicked: {
                    if (hasUserMenuProperty.hasUserMenu()
                            && !globalUserManager.hasAccessToPrivilege("controlMap"))
                        return

                    map.pointPositionModel.remove(map.pointPositionModel.index(index, 0))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
Component.onCompleted: {
    pointsPositionComboBox.popup.contentItem.implicitHeight = Qt.binding(function () {
        // Делаем отображение только 10 элементов (остальные скроллом только)
        return Math.min(pointsPositionRect.height * 10,
                        pointsPositionComboBox.popup.contentItem.contentHeight)
    })
}
```

How to display a list of combo box elements from the top, and not from the bottom as in the photo?

P.s. I set implicitHeight for displaying element of combobox in *Component.onCompleted*
P.s.2 Now it looks like picture:
[image: picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the `implicitHeight` of the `Popup` to set its `y` property. Have a look at the source below. The default behavior of the `Popup` is when ever it fits below it will open up below, if there is not enough space below it will open above the `ComboBox`. The following code is a tweaked version of the [Customizing ComboBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-combobox) example from the Qt documentation.

[image]

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    width: 400
    height: 300

    Row {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        ComboBox {
            id: control

            model: ["First", "Second", "Third"]

            delegate: ItemDelegate {
                width: control.width
                contentItem: Text {
                    text: modelData
                    color: "#21be2b"
                    font: control.font
                    elide: Text.ElideRight
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                }
                highlighted: control.highlightedIndex === index
            }

            indicator: Canvas {
                id: canvas
                x: control.width - width - control.rightPadding
                y: control.topPadding + (control.availableHeight - height) / 2
                width: 12
                height: 8
                contextType: "2d"

                Connections {
                    target: control
                    function onPressedChanged() { canvas.requestPaint(); }
                }

                onPaint: {
                    context.reset();
                    context.moveTo(0, 0);
                    context.lineTo(width, 0);
                    context.lineTo(width / 2, height);
                    context.closePath();
                    context.fillStyle = control.pressed ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b";
                    context.fill();
                }
            }

            contentItem: Text {
                leftPadding: 10
                rightPadding: control.indicator.width + control.spacing
                text: control.displayText
                font: control.font
                color: control.pressed ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                elide: Text.ElideRight
            }

            background: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 120
                implicitHeight: 40
                border.color: control.pressed ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
                border.width: control.visualFocus ? 2 : 1
                radius: 2
            }

            popup: Popup {
                y: myCheckBox.checked ? -implicitHeight + 1 : control.height - 1
                width: control.width
                implicitHeight: contentItem.implicitHeight
                padding: 1

                contentItem: ListView {
                    clip: true
                    implicitHeight: contentHeight
                    model: control.popup.visible ? control.delegateModel : null
                    currentIndex: control.highlightedIndex

                    ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
                }

                background: Rectangle {
                    border.color: "#21be2b"
                    radius: 2
                }
            }
        }

        CheckBox {
            id: myCheckBox
            text: qsTr("above")
        }
    }
}
```